# Difference between CQ5.6 and AEM6.0?

Tags: aem

What are the differences between **CQ 5.6** and **AEM 6.0** in regards to the **Technology Stack**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the major tech stack upgrades in AEM 6.1/6.0

1. Jackrabbit Oak: 
   Compared to JCR, Oak offers improved performance, scalability. You also have an option of using NoSQL DB like MongoDB as persistence layer to support clustering and user generated data scenarios.
2. [Sightly](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/sightly.html):  New templating language, makes markup look beautiful, enforces separation of the markup from logic and also offers XSS protection by default.
3. Touch UI: Classic UI in CQ5 which is ExtJS based has been upgraded to Touch UI which supports touch enabled devices - built using [Coral UI](https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/touch-ui/coral-ui/index.html) framework.
4. Search - Apache Solr: Default search engine in CQ5 was Lucene, this has been upgraded to Solr. You can now configure Solr server as search engine for your AEM application.

Check out the release notes to get the complete lowdown of what's been upgraded in AEM [6.0](https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/aem/6-0/release-notes.html) and [6.1](https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/aem/6-1/release-notes.html)

Answer (score 1):

The other major change is in the Communities...
Please look at this article for more details.
http://cq-ops.tumblr.com/post/86504895994/whats-new-in-aem-60